# Unable to find a way to plot the data in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having a data where:

```
pd["states"] = ['AX','IP','US']
pd["CATEGORY"] = ['good','bad',......,'bad','good']
```

I want to plot a stacked bar chart, where states will go to x axis and y axis will have count of good and bad against each states, which should be distinguished by different colors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df2 = churn_df.groupby(['states', 'CATEGORY'])    ['states'].count().unstack('CATEGORY').fillna(0)
df2[['good','bad']].plot(kind='bar', stacked=True, width=1)
```

This will help , I guess.